# bash environment variable with whitespace character. cd without quotes

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, whitespace

I'm trying to succeed with the following in bash:

```
mkdir "any dir"
export DIR="any dir"
cd $DIR
```

and it gives me `-bash: cd: any: No such file or directory`

I know it would work with

```
cd "$DIR"
```

but I do not want to use this because a ton of scripts I do not want to touch uses `cd $DIR`.

Is there really no way to achieve this with bash? Even the Windows prompt allows this by

```
mkdir "any dir"
set DIR=any^ dir
cd %DIR%
```

Comment: If those scripts use `cd $DIR`, then those are bugs that need to be fixed. Don't try to work around them; fix them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible kludge is to use `[[:blank:]]` instead of space like this:

```
export DIR='any[[:blank:]]dir'
cd $DIR
```

Now it will work without error since shell won't treat `any[[:blank:]]dir` as 2 different arguments.

`[[:blank:]]` is POSIX property that matches space or tab character.

Comment: Thanks! Not easy to find this answer :)

Comment: One (extremely minor) caveat: this won't work if `set -f` is in effect, because `any[[:blank:]]dir` will not undergo file name generation, and `[[:blank:]]` will be treated literally.

Comment: It leaves the possibility of that "any<tab>dir" and "any<space>dir" might somehow be confused, (assuming both exist), or worse, exploited, (assuming both exist, secretly).

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not work with any scripts that *aren't* buggy, i.e. those that use double-quotes properly. It'll also fail if buggy scripts are chained i.e. if "any[[:blank:]]dir" gets glob-expanded to "any dir" by one script, then it passes that to a second script that treats that as "any" "dir". I'm with chepner on this: it's much better to fix the scripts than to kluge around the bug.

Answer (score 0):

just add DIR between " character.

```
mkdir "any dir"
export DIR="any dir"
cd "$DIR"   ## change $DIR to "$DIR"
```

Comment: On my Lubuntu box, this method doesn't work on **dash** (POSIX), or **bash**.

Comment: As mentioned I am not willing to touch the `cd $DIR` line.

Answer (score 0):

While it may be preferable to repair the way the variable is referenced with the "cd" command, in a situation where this option is inaccessible,

You can use the following approach in shell;

```
export DIR="any?dir"
cd $DIR
```

This is including a single character wildcard in the environment variable, and the cd command will match the space in "any dir" as a result.

The problem is that this will only work when accessing a directory or file whose name *matches* the variable. You can't use it to *create* any directories or files.

Comment: Replacing white space with ? worked for me in windows ubuntu 22.